# vba excel sms for api

Tags: vba, api, sms, excel-2007

I would like that every time I register an appointment, the client is notified by sms.
You will find attached a vba code for this purpose for sending sms.
The script seems to be executing.
On the other hand, do not deliver the sms as expected.
Someone to help me figure out what is missing please

```
Sub send_SMS_RDV()


    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

        
        
        '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        '''''''''essai code xfactor'''''''''''''''''''''
            Set objHTTP = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
          Dim Recipient As String
           Dim Message As String
           
    Dim rowname As String
    Dim rowprestardv As String
    
    
    Dim rowtimerdv, rownumber, rowdaterdv, x  As String
    
    rowtimerdv = Worksheets("PLANNING").Range("I4").Value
    rowprestardv = Worksheets("PLANNING").Range("H4").Value
    rowname = Worksheets("PLANNING").Range("N4").Value
    rownumber = Worksheets("PLANNING").Range("O4").Value
    rowdaterdv = Worksheets("PLANNING").Range("Q4").Value
    
    
    x = "237"
    Recipient = "x&lastrownumber"
           

'
    If rowdaterdv = Worksheets("PLANNING").Range("P32").Value Then
'
        Message = "Dear  " & rowname & ",  your appointment has  been register at : " & rowtimerdv & " Contact us for any changes. Merci"
           Else
'
        Message = "Dear  " & rowname & ",  your appointment has  been register at : " & rowdaterdv & " Contact us for any changes. Merci"""

'
' 
        End If
           
           
            'Set vars where phone numbers and msg are set in your sheet'

            URL = api.smsfactor.com/send?text=" + Message + "&to=" + Recipient
            objHTTP.Open "GET", URL, False
            objHTTP.SetRequestHeader "Authorization", "Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIzNDcwOSIsImlhdCI6MTYwMTk5NzM4N30.VbWdRwVwtIn5JtwNYjeJ8imnM_2bYskRIg2O6uZG5fA" 'Your Token'
            objHTTP.SetRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json"
            objHTTP.send ("")
        
        
        
      End Sub
```

Comment: Use `Option Explicit` to ensure all of your variables are properly declared.

Comment: Did you just post your private API token on the public internet? I think anyone can send an SMS using your account now.

Answer (score 0):

Your `URL` variable looks wrong. That would need to be a string but it's not a proper string. You are missing a start quote mark and you are using `+` for concatenation where I would expect to see `&` instead.

Try changing it to this:

```
URL = "api.smsfactor.com/send?text=" & Message & "&to=" & Recipient
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your contribution.
I solved the problem.
here is what I modified to make it work.

```
 Recipient = 237 & rownumber
```

and after url

```
url = Replace(url, " ", "%20")
```

However, I would like to configure with another provider but have problems again

```
Sub send_SMS_Fact()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'   Declaring varibles for sending sms

    Dim objWinHTTP  As Object
    Dim response, send As String
    Dim sURL As String
    Dim API As String
    Dim SenderID As String
    Dim Recipient, Message As String
'   Declaring varibles for Application
    Dim rowname As String
    Dim rowtypevente As String
    
    
    Dim rowamount, rownumber, x  As String
    Worksheets("FACTURATION").Activate
    
    rowtypevente = Worksheets("FACTURATION").Range("H11").Text
    rowamount = Worksheets("FACTURATION").Range("M11").Text
    rowname = Worksheets("FACTURATION").Range("S11").Text
    rownumber = Worksheets("FACTURATION").Range("T11").Text
    
    
    API = "Um9kcnlnMTIzOnNhbG9tZQ=="
    x = "237"
    Recipient = x & rownumber
    SenderID = "TechSoft-SMS"
'   Preparation sms

    If rowtypevente = "VENTE DIFF" Then
        
        Message = "Dear  " & rowname & ",  The amount of your invoice which is: " & rowamount & " remains to be paid as soon as possible"
            Else
            rowtypevente = "VENTE"


        Message = "Dear  " & rowname & ",  We thank you for your loyalty and hope to have satisfied you. Best regards and see you soon"
    
    End If
'  Checking for valid mobile number

    If rownumber <> "700000000" Then

        
 

    Else
        Recipient = CStr(rownumber)

 
    End If



''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
''''''test protocole url'''''
    Set objWinHTTP = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")

    sURL = app.techsoft-web-agency.com/sms/api"
    sURL = Replace(sURL, " ", "%20")
    Request = "&apikey=" & API & URLEncode(Apikey) & "&number=" & Recipient & URLEncode(Number)
    Request = Request & "&message=" & Message & URLEncode(Message)
    Request = Request & "&expediteur=" & SenderID & URLEncode(Expediteur) & "&msg_id=" & MsgID

    objWinHTTP.Open "GET", URL & Request, False
    objWinHTTP.SetTimeouts 30000, 30000, 30000, 30000
    objWinHTTP.send
    If objWinHTTP.StatusText = "OK" Then
        strReturn = objWinHTTP.ResponseText
        Debug.Print strReturn
    End If

    Set objWinHTTP = Nothing
    send = strReturn



End Sub
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

Public Function URLEncode(sRawURL) As String
    On Error GoTo Catch
    Dim iLoop As Integer
    Dim sRtn As String
    Dim sTmp As String
    Const sValidChars = "1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz:/.?=_-$()~&"
    If Len(sRawURL) > 0 Then
        For iLoop = 1 To Len(sRawURL)
            sTmp = Mid(sRawURL, iLoop, 1)
            If InStr(1, sValidChars, sTmp, vbBinaryCompare) = 0 Then
                sTmp = Hex(Asc(sTmp))
                If sTmp = "20" Then
                    sTmp = "+"
                ElseIf Len(sTmp) = 1 Then
                    sTmp = "%0" & sTmp
                Else
                    sTmp = "%" & sTmp
                End If
            End If
            sRtn = sRtn & sTmp
        Next iLoop
        URLEncode = sRtn
    End If
Finally:
        Exit Function
Catch:
        URLEncode = ""
        Resume Finally
End Function
```

This is how I configured the new url according to the documentation I found on their site.
But at the line "objWinHTTP.Open" GET ", URL & Request, False" I am told that the url uses an unrecognized protocol